# Jackson YAML Serialization with and without quotes

Tags: jackson, jackson-dataformat-yaml

I am trying to Serialize YAML where I need some String field values with quotes and some without quotes (Raw) like

```yaml
name: "John"
department: Finance
```

I am able to achieve the no quotes with

```java
YAMLFactory().enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES)
```

but I need a mix of values with and without quotes. How do I achieve this?